# Is it possible to interact to other app like getting the id what view they tapped?

Tags: android

I'm developing an application that can determine the id of view on external app, 
(e.g. I have two application, App1 and App2, what I'm going to make is App2 that can determine what App1 doing, like getting the id of the button on App1 using App2 and if gets an error the App2 will catch the log error)

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can interact between 2 application using bound service and Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL).

Check below link for more details.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions are communicating with a server that stores the information that you need.
Or write the actions on a file accessible by both apps.

Obviously, all the solutions have pros and cons. In the first one, you need to have access to the internet, on the second you need to handle readings and writings simultaneous, etc.